# analyzing this algorithm (big-o)

Tags: c, combinatorics, asymptotic-complexity

**Problem**

What is this algorithm doing? What does 0x01 represent?  What does it mean that m = m >> 1 within the inner while loop?    What is this algorithm big-O of?

```
while(n>0)
{
     m = n;
     while(m)
     {
          if(m & 0x01)
          {
                c++;
          }
          m = m >> 1;
     }
}
```

**Attempt**

1. By looking @ the algorithm, I understand that m is right-shifted one place.
   (E.g., if m = 1010, m >> 1 = 0101.  Is that correct?)
2. Because there is a nested while loop, and because each while iterates n time, my guess is that this algorithm is O(n^2).  Is that correct?

Comment: bitcount of "1" s. Number of "1"s in n count for infinitely many times.

Comment: This is not an `O(n^2)` loop. It is `O(infinity)` since `n` never changes.

Comment: If right shift in this compiler/machine extends the sign bit, and m is signed and n is not signed but the same size as m and has that top bit set, would the inner loop also run forever?

Comment: At least you can go and say that you've "programmed `c++`".

Comment: Since we are all generous people, lets just assume the example left out a line `n /= 2;` or `++n;` or something similar.

Comment: @LeeMeador: almost certainly, yes (but everything is "almost" when mixing signed and unsigned because of evil ones' complement machines :-) )

Comment: Oh. I forgot about negative zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`What is this algorithm doing?`  For a value of `n`, the number of bits that are on in `n` is added to `c`.

`0x01` represents the value `1`. It is being used as a bit mask to check whether the lowest bit of `m` is on. If it is, then it increments `c`. This is the bit-counting part.
Then, `m` is right-shifted once to move the next bit down into the position of LSB (least significant bit). The `while(m)` will stop once `m` is equal to `0`; that is, when `m` has no more bits on.

And the algorithmic complexity depends on what you're doing with `n`. If you're decrementing it, then your algorithm is `O(n)` since the inner section (the `while(m)`) is constant (since there is a maximum number of bits in an integer, and that is probably 32).

The complexity is probably `O(n * 32)`, but since constants are taken out of Big-Oh notation, you end up with `O(n)`.

Comment: Ignoring the bugs mentioned elsewhere, notice the loop stops when it becomes zero. So perhaps O(log2(n)) would be a better measure.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is counting the number of "1" bits in m. 
Its cost is O(log m) because every iteration it's halving the value of m, until it reaches 0.

(If you consider m to be an integer of fixed size, say, 32 bits, then you could say the inner loop is O(1) because it always makes at most 32 operations which is a constant number)

The outer loop, as some have pointed out, never finishes because n never changes. (unless n is 0).

So overall this code is O(infinity), it never finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Well... for one thing, this function will actually never exit.  The `while( n > 0 )` at the start will remain constantly true, because 'n' is never modified within the loop.  So that'll be a problem if you try to run it.

But to answer your questions:

The `m & 0x01` will basically check to see if 'm' is an odd number.  It does this by doing a bitwise operation between `m` and `0x01`.  The value `0x01` is a hexidecimal representation of the value `1`.  Doing an `&` operation between them will cause each bit to be compared against one another (in binary), and set to `1` if and only if both matching bits have a value of one.  For more information one that, do some research on binary and hexidecimal representations, and the bitwise operators.

The `>>` is another bitwise operator which shifts all the bits in a value by one spot.  In the decimal world, that's equivalent to dividing by 2.  So that line is causing the value of `m` to be divided by two each time it gets to that line of code.  There is a mirror operator of `<<` for shifting the bits in the opposite direction, and equates to multiplying by 2 instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps n would be -1 and the loop would never run. Perhaps n = 1 and the loop would run forever. I think there are two choices on that.

Comment: Of course, yeah... it's either going to not run at all, or run forever.  Sorry, I figured that was implied just by the code itself.